# Thr Video doesn't play after downloading from server

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm using video view and want to download the video from server by clicking Play Button and after downloading It will be play automatically,but it doesn't play. It's downloaded but doesn't play.

This is my current code for playing:

```
void downloadFile() {
        try {
            AudioURL = "http://" + Const.pathSelected;
            URL url = new URL(AudioURL);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            //set the path where we want to save the file
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //create a new file, to save the downloaded file
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot, "/Story/");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir();
            }

            String[] pathname = Const.pathSelected.split("/");
            fileName = pathname[3];
            OutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(new File(file, fileName));
            Const.localPath = file.getPath() + "/" + fileName;
            //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            .......
            //close the output stream when complete //
            fileOutput.close();


            final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                runtime.exec("su -c am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                   uri = Uri.parse(Const.localPath);
            //        uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Const.localPath));

                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                videoView.requestFocus();
                videoView.start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are trying to play video before the download gets complete, in such case it wont play, try the below code to download videos (Here i am passing ArrayList of URL's and updating the progress as i am downloading multiple videos once)

```
class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, String, Void>
{
    String file_name = "";
    String total_urls = "";
    String current_no ="";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... passed_url)
    {
        ArrayList<String> al_url = new ArrayList<String>();
        al_url = passed_url[0];
        total_urls = ""+al_url.size();
        for (int s = 0; s < al_url.size(); s++) {
            int count = 0;
            try {
                //URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URL url = new URL(al_url.get(s));
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("" + al_url.get(s), "/");
                file_name = "";
                current_no = ""+(s+1);
                while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    file_name = tokenizer.nextToken();
                }


                int lenght_of_file = connection.getContentLength();

                File outputFile = new File(Utilities.ADS_DIR_PATH, file_name);

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 1024);
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenght_of_file));

                    output.write(data, 0, count);

                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Toast.makeText(DownloadTask.this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        Intent display_intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, NewDisplay.class);
        display_intent.putExtra("LOC_NAME", loc_name);
        startActivity(display_intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        txtv_desc.setText("Downloading"+" ("+current_no+"/"+total_urls+")... "+ file_name + "     " + values[0] + "%");
    }
}
```

and call this using

```
DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
task.execute(al_videoURLs);
```